# Fading Action Bar Android shows only one item in List

Tags: android, android-listview, android-actionbar

I was trying to use the famous Fading Action Bar(FAB) library in my app and I am stuck with a weird problem. If I don't use the FAB library my listview loads just fine but if I use the FAB library, there is only one element in the listview rather than 10.

I have imported the FAB library as a library project and provided it the appropriate resources it needs. Here is my code :

```
 public class JobList extends Activity {
    ArrayList<String> jobList;
    ListView lv;
    ProgressDialog progress;
    HashMap<String,JobItem> jobMap;
    HashMap<String,String> positionAndIdMap;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_job_list);

     FadingActionBarHelper helper = new FadingActionBarHelper()
     .actionBarBackground(R.drawable.ab_background)
     .headerLayout(R.layout.header)
     .contentLayout(R.layout.activity_job_list);
     setContentView(helper.createView(this));
     helper.initActionBar(this);


    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    jobList = new ArrayList<String>();
    jobMap = new HashMap<String, JobItem>();
    positionAndIdMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String url = "https://cs5.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/query";
    url += "?q="+ URLEncoder.encode("SELECT Id,Name,tc9_ti__Client_Name__c,Date_Posted_Formatted__c,ts2__Employment_Type__c,ts2__Job_Description__c,ts2__Status__c from ts2__Job__c Limit 10");
    requestWithSomeHttpHeaders(url, getApplicationContext());

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String jobId = positionAndIdMap.get(""+position);
            JobItem item = jobMap.get(jobId);
            Intent jobIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), JobDetail.class);
            jobIntent.putExtra("obj",item);
            startActivity(jobIntent);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+jobList.get(position), 500).show();
        }
    });
}


public void requestWithSomeHttpHeaders(String reqUrl, Context context){
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    String finalResponse ="";
    Context con = context;
    String url = reqUrl;

    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, 
        new Response.Listener<String>() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // response
                Log.d("Response", response);
                progress.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    try {
                        // Getting Array of Contacts
                        JSONArray records = jObj.getJSONArray("records");

                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for(int i = 0; i < records.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject c = records.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String title = c.getString("Name");
                            String Id = c.getString("Id");
                            String jobStatus = c.getString("ts2__Status__c");
                            String datePosted = c.getString("Date_Posted_Formatted__c");
                            String clientName = c.getString("tc9_ti__Client_Name__c");
                            String employmentType = c.getString("ts2__Employment_Type__c");
                            String jobDescription = c.getString("ts2__Job_Description__c");

                            JobItem jItem = new JobItem(Id,title,clientName,datePosted,employmentType,jobDescription,jobStatus);
                            jobList.add(title);
                            Log.d("Job list:"+i, ""+title);
                            positionAndIdMap.put(""+i,Id);
                            jobMap.put(Id, jItem);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.d("Json:", ""+jObj);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }
               if(jobList.size()>0){

                   lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, jobList));
               }else{
                   setContentView(R.layout.empty);
               }

            }
        }, 
        new Response.ErrorListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("ERROR","error => "+error.toString());
            }
        }
    ) {     
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError { 
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
                String sessionId = RequestHandler.TOKEN;
                params.put("X-PrettyPrint", "1");
                params.put("Authorization", "OAuth " + sessionId);
                return params;  
        }
    };

    queue.add(postRequest);

    progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait...",
            "Loading List Of Jobs..."); 
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.job_list, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

The above code compiles without any errors, but the List contains only one element. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? If I remove the FAB part from the code above and set the content normally then the list loads 10 elements. Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: I have the same situation now. Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: Apparently not :(  I have even tried custom listview and standard listview implementation but the same result. So I guess it's a bug.

Comment: sorry to hear that :/ thanks for answer

Comment: Did someone find any solutions to this problem?

Comment: @endian Nope ! I have created an issue regarding the same here : https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar/issues/34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this as well. The solution is that your listView's ID must be `android.R.id.list` since that's the id he's using to determine if you have a listView otherwise it falls back to scrollView.